# Android EditText: enable only scrolling but stop comsuming clicks

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-edittext, horizontalscrollview

I am contributing to an app project and I have this issue.

I have a Horizontal LinearLayout with an ArrayAdapter list of Items: image -- EditText -- image

I use EditText to enable scrolling horizontally a long text field while disabling cursor and click events. The parent layout needs to manage the click event on the items + horizontal swipe to change tabs in Main View

The code works properly:

- If EditText has a long text: I can scroll horizontally the text to read it all. At the end of the text, the parent layout takes the swipe and can change tabs
- I can long touch on the EditText to enable a select checkmark from the parent layout
- The cursor and slider are properly hidden in the EditText

The only issue is that EditText consumes the simple click events and never passes them to the parent layout. When I click the images or when I click on the right/left of the EditText, the parent layout properly captures the click action on the adapter item. If I click directly on the EditText, the event is consumed and never reaches the parent layout setOnItemClickListener.

Here's a short video of how it is working now. The click at 10 seconds position in video must be done outside the text: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P306p7AcwAI

Here is the xml sample:
https://github.com/PhilZ-cwm6/SMBSync2/blob/philz/SMBSync2/src/main/res/layout/sync_task_item_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile_list_sync_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sync_task_master_icon"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|top"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_16_server" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sync_task_master_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="Master"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sync_task_direction_image"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_enabled" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sync_task_target_icon"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_16_server" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sync_task_target_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="Target"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the adapter code extract:
https://github.com/PhilZ-cwm6/SMBSync2/blob/philz/SMBSync2/src/main/java/com/sentaroh/android/SMBSync2/AdapterSyncTask.java

```
public class AdapterSyncTask extends ArrayAdapter<SyncTaskItem> {
    final public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        final SyncTaskItem o = getItem(position);

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(id, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tv_row_master = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.sync_task_master_info);
            holder.tv_row_target = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.sync_task_target_info);
        }

        if (o != null) {
            holder.tv_row_master.setText("source dir path");
            holder.tv_row_master.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS); //disable auto-correct highlight in EditText

            holder.tv_row_target.setText(destination dir path);
            holder.tv_row_target.setTextColor(mTextColor);
            holder.tv_row_target.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS); //disable auto-correct highlight in EditText
        }
        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        EditText tv_row_master, tv_row_target;
    }
}
```

And the ActivityMain that needs the onClick events:
https://github.com/PhilZ-cwm6/SMBSync2/blob/philz/SMBSync2/src/main/java/com/sentaroh/android/SMBSync2/ActivityMain.java

```
private void setSyncTaskListItemClickListener() {
    mGp.syncTaskListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SyncTaskItem item = mGp.syncTaskAdapter.getItem(position);
            editSyncTask(item.getSyncTaskName(), item.isSyncTaskAuto(), position);
        }
    });
}
```

These are really simple code snippets

Basically, the original code works properly with a TextView but long text path cannot be viewed/scrolled in a single line. Using HorizontalScrollView works also but doesn't pass any event, include swipe and long press to the parent if the click happens on the text field.

The EditText trick fixes all except the simple click events when they happen on the EditTex box. Wired because long touch and swipe are properly passed. Also, the setOnItemClickListener doesn't capture any event when clicking on the EditText, but captures them if it is a TextView

Any idea how to fix this ? I thought about a custom EditText but ended up unsure how would the ArrayAdapter get the EditText position. Am I obliged to use a second adapter for the EditText ?

best regards

Edit: I can add this code to the getView() of Adapter:

```
holder.tv_row_target.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //click events of EditText are captured
    }
});
```

However, I cannot propagate them to the ListView or a Parent view from the `onClick()`
This would avoid a heavy rewrite in code based on actions that Parent should do on click

Comment: did you check `android:editable="false"`?

Comment: I just tried `android:editable="false"` but it doesn't help. OnClick event is consumed by the EditText

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: see next post with proper fix to preserve the native ListView animation**

I fixed it this way:
in adapter:

```
holder.tv_row_target.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((ActivityMain) mContext).dispatchSyncTaskListItemClick(o, position);
    }
});
```

In MainActivity:

```
public void dispatchSyncTaskListItemClick(SyncTaskItem item, int position) {
  // my actions
}
```

That way, I can pass the needed info (position, object item) to the activity

I am open to any other suggestion to simply propagate the click to the parent ListView so that it handles it directly

Answer (score 0):

**Proper fix:**

I post this for any one having the same issue. I saw so many threads on this but no one ever came with a good fix

My previous answer has an issue: it doesn't preserve the native ListView onClick fading animation

I tried the performclick() but it is the same.

I finally fixed it completely using MotionEvent to pass the touch events to the list view

In Adapter: I set the onClick listeners for click and long click and send the action to MainActivity where the ListView action code is present

Adapter listeners:

```
holder.tv_row_target.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((ActivityMain) mContext).dispatchSyncTaskListItemClick(o, position);
    }
});

holder.tv_row_target.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        v.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
        ((ActivityMain) mContext).dispatchSyncTaskListLongClick(o, position);
        return true;//notify long touch event is consumed
    }
});
```

In Main Activity: The `setOnItemLongClickListener` and `setOnItemClickListener` must be set there. The issue was to click the EditText or a an icon which handles touch and perform the ListView action and animation

```
// simulate click on teh ListView item
public void dispatchSyncTaskListItemClick(SyncTaskItem item, int position) {
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    int first_visible_pos = mGp.syncTaskListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

    View v = mGp.syncTaskListView.getChildAt(position - first_visible_pos);

    float x = v.getX() + 1;//view items start at 0, MotionEvent doesn't handle the UP action at 0
    float y = v.getY();

    //first touch
    MotionEvent motionDown = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
    motionDown.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
    mGp.syncTaskListView.onTouchEvent(motionDown);

    //release touch
    downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    MotionEvent motionUp = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
    motionUp.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
    mGp.syncTaskListView.onTouchEvent(motionUp);

    motionUp.recycle();
    motionDown.recycle();
}

// simulate long touch
public void dispatchSyncTaskListLongClick(SyncTaskItem item, int position) {
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    int first_visible_pos = mGp.syncTaskListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

    View v = mGp.syncTaskListView.getChildAt(position - first_visible_pos);

    MotionEvent motion = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, v.getX(), v.getY(), 0);
    motion.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
    mGp.syncTaskListView.onTouchEvent(motion);
    motion.recycle();
}
```

The hardest part was the `x+1` because my View started at float x = 0.0, and the UP action was not considered until it is > 0. Not sure why ? ACTION_DOWN handles it properly

The other thing to take care of is the `getChildAt`: it returns the view position starting from first visible position and not the adapter passed position. Else, you get a null returned view.

Now, it works just like when interacting with the ListView

New edit: added `v.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);` to remove the duplicate haptic feedback on long touch !

Remaining issue: I feel all this is a workaround. There is still a small delay on the animation trigger when long click. The ideal would be the EditText View completely letting ListView to handle the onClick

So probably only a custom HorizontalScrollView or a custom EditText would fix it